# 'social' is not a registered namespace when integrating social_django

Tags: python, django, docker, namespaces, django-socialauth

I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of them seemed quite the same as my situation. The error I receive looks like this:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://web/login/auth0

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.5.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'social_django',
 'cx_benchmark.apps.authentication']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  77.                 extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]

During handling of the above exception ('social'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/social_django/utils.py" in wrapper
  37.                 uri = reverse(redirect_uri, args=(backend,))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  87.                     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /login/auth0
Exception Value: 'social' is not a registered namespace
```

My application is Dockerized, and I am attempting to integrate Auth0 and `social_django`. I am using nginx, gunicorn, and postgres in my stack. I mainly followed this tutorial to get running: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/django

I have `social_django` and the sub-application, `authentication` installed in my main settings file:

```
# /src/my_app/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    'my_app.apps.authentication',
]
```

My Auth0 integration settings look like this:

```
# /src/my_app/settings.py

SOCIAL_AUTH_TRAILING_SLASH = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN = '[hidden]'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY = '[hidden]'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET = '[hidden]'

SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SCOPE = [
    'openid',
    'profile'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = {
    'my_app.apps.authentication.auth0backend.Auth0',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
}

LOGIN_URL = "/login/auth0"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

My main application's urls.py looks like this:

```
# /src/my_app/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('my_app.apps.authentication.urls', namespace='authentication')),
]
```

And the urls.py for the authentication app looks like this:

```
# /src/my_app/apps/authentication/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'authentication'

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index),
    url(r'^dashboard', views.dashboard),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    url(r'^', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

When I build the Docker image, run it and access `/login/auth0`, I get the error described above.

I am using:

```
certifi (2017.7.27.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
defusedxml (0.5.0)
Django (1.11) # <---
ecdsa (0.13)
future (0.16.0)
gunicorn (19.6.0)
idna (2.6)
oauthlib (2.0.6)
pip (9.0.1)
psycopg2 (2.6.2)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
PyJWT (1.5.3)
python-jose (1.4.0)
python3-openid (3.1.0)
requests (2.18.4)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
setuptools (36.6.0)
six (1.11.0)
social-auth-app-django (2.0.0) # <---
social-auth-core (1.5.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: the urls patterns look fine, some posts are suggesting that an update to django 1.10.5 (or higher) solves this issue

Comment: @PRMoureu I just swapped it out for django 1.11 and the same issue occurs. Also updated the version in my original post. (For clarity's sake, I was originally using 1.10.)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to **/src/my_app/apps/authentication/urls.py**:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = "my_app:social"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it make sense then, You are using two base url. django.contrib.auth.urls and social_django.urls have same url. I think you need to change either of one. If i am wrong then please ignore. And if it help then let me know. Thanks.